# React component state confict

Tags: reactjs

**I have a component like this**

```
<Home>
  <PostBox key={1} />
  <PostBox key={2} />
</Home>
```

**PostBox component like this**

```
const [renderImage, setRenderImage] = useState(null)
const [image, setImage] = useState(null)

const handleFileSelect = (e) => {
        const selectedImage = e.target.files[0]
        setImage(selectedImage)
        console.log(selectedImage)
        if (selectedImage.size > MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
            setImage(null)
            console.log('Please select a file less than 2MB.')
            return
        }
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = () => {
            setRenderImage(reader.result);
        };

        if (selectedImage) {
            reader.readAsDataURL(selectedImage);
        }

    }
return (<div>
<input className='hidden' type="file" name="fileInput" onChange={handleFileSelect} accept='image/*' id="fileInput" />
    {
                (image) && <div className='relative'>
                    <div onClick={() => { setImage(null); setRenderImage(null) }} className='absolute top-5 left-5 text-3xl p-2 rounded-full bg-gray-200 cursor-pointer hover:text-red-600 hover:bg-gray-100'>
                        <MdOutlineClose />
                    </div>
                    <img className='' src={renderImage} alt="user selected image" />
                </div>
            }
</div>)
```

When I'm trying to select image in second Postbox.
It render in first Postbox

I want when i select image in second component it should render in second component

Comment: It is working well on my sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-moon-z4f9hc?file=/src/App.js
Also, you don't need to add a `key` prop if you are not rendering a list of elements (from an array for example)

Comment: yes this is working in your send box
but this is not working in vs code

Comment: Can you provide the full code of your PostBox component then ?